# Selenium find array contents on page

Tags: c#, arrays, selenium

I'm using Visual Studio with Selenium to build an application that goes to a web page and finds if the contents of an array are on the page. I'm running into an issue with searching the page for the array contents.. Right now it finds nothing, so it clicks to go to the next page when it shouldn't.

The array comes from a CSV file I'm loading in and it needs to search the page for a match of any of the records from the CSV file and stops.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    private double timeOut;

    private void bttnImportBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "CSV|*.csv";
        var fileInputs = new List<string>();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String chosenFile = ofd.FileName;
            String safeFileName = ofd.SafeFileName;

            try
            {
                // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
                // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(chosenFile))
                {
                    string line;
                    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                    // the file is reached.
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(line);
                        fileInputs.Add(line);
                        //Console.Write(string.Join(" ", fileInputs));

                        var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\");


                            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("MySite");


                        var WebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.XPath("/html/body/a[2]"))));
                        while (1==1) {
                            try
                            {
                                var result = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(fileInputs.ToString())); 
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (NoSuchElementException n)
                            {
                                var nextBttn = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/a[2]");
                                nextBttn.Click();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception entry)
            {
                // Let the user know what went wrong.
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i would have left a comment but am not allowed to yet. Do you have the CSV file?

I believe you are trying to find the Link text incorrectly.

Currently calling ToString() on the list

```
 var result = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(fileInputs.ToString()));
```

should probably be

```
 var result = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(line));
```

Comment: move your  var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\andre_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\");

Comment: You should probably put it in a background thread there are lots of examples online. If you are running in Winforms you can stop the error by calling Application.DoEvents () in your read loop. (I think it's bad form though)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The proposed method of searching by "line" is running in to an issue. It is only searching for the first record from the CSV file instead of any of the records. Example: the file has the following records: apple, banana, orange. It is only looking for apple and skips over banana and orange